# Extending Pytorch: Python vs. C++ vs. CUDA

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, autograd

I have been trying to implement a custom Conv2d module where grad_input (dx) and grad_weight (dw) are calculated by using different grad_output (dy) values. I implemented this by extending `torch.autograd` as in Pytorch tutorials.

However I am confused by the information [in this link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html#backward-pass).

- Is extending the autograd.Function not enough?
- What is the difference
  between writing a new autograd function in Python vs C++?
- How about
  the CUDA implementations in
  /torch/nn/blob/master/lib/THNN/generic/SpatialConvolutionMM.c where
  dx and dw calculated? Should I change them too?

Here is my custom function:

```
class myCustomConv2d(torch.autograd.Function):
@staticmethod
def forward(ctx, x, w, bias=None, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1):
    ctx.save_for_backward(x, w, bias)
    ctx.stride = stride
    ctx.padding = padding
    ctx.dilation = dilation
    ctx.groups = groups
    out = F.conv2d(x, w, bias, stride, padding, dilation, groups)
    return out

@staticmethod
def backward(ctx, grad_output):
    input, weight, bias = ctx.saved_tensors
    stride = ctx.stride
    padding = ctx.padding
    dilation = ctx.dilation
    groups = ctx.groups
    grad_input = grad_weight = grad_bias = None

    dy_for_inputs = myspecialfunction1(grad_output)
    dy_for_weights = myspecialfunction2(grad_output)

    grad_input = torch.nn.grad.conv2d_input(input.shape, weight, dy_for_inputs , stride, padding, dilation, groups)
    grad_weight = torch.nn.grad.conv2d_weight(input, weight.shape, dy_for_weights , stride, padding, dilation, groups)

    if bias is not None and ctx.needs_input_grad[2]:
        grad_bias = dy_for_weights .sum((0,2,3)).squeeze(0)

    return grad_input, grad_weight, grad_bias, None, None, None, None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is extending the autograd.Function not enough?

It is enough if your code reuses Pytorch components wrapped within Python interface (which seems to be the case). Gradient is composed automatically.

> What is the difference between writing a new autograd function in Python vs C++?

Performance, the more custom your operation is (and the harder it is to compose it from exstsing Pytorch operations), the more performance improvement you would obtain.

> How about the CUDA implementations in /torch/nn/blob/master/lib/THNN/generic/SpatialConvolutionMM.c where dx and dw calculated? Should I change them too?

No need for that, unless you want to create specialized ops for CUDA